# MySql trigger not firing (At all)

Tags: mysql, triggers

I had trigger before insert, working. Now it does not fire at all.

Copy table & trigger to another db and it works OK.

Tryed to recreate trigger all togther, and there is no change.

If I look at information_schema, triggers table, I see that problematc trigger differs from others in  SQL_MODE value which is NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO as compared to all others that have: STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION.

If that is the cause at all ?

Comment: just recreated that trigger from scratch, NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO became STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION, so it appears that is not reason for problem.  There is no change, it does not fire.

Comment: http://shrani.si/f/1U/11W/24T9L4ON/tmp.jpg

Comment: further:SELECT @@sql_mode returns STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION on problematic server and empty string on server where all is OK

Answer (score 0):

The trick is:

```
#Set the SQL mode to strict
#comented, coz strict blocks insert althought key field is filled on before insert trigger
#sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Restart server.